# Разрабатываемый метод должен возвращать истину, если массив упорядочен (т.е. каждый следующий элемент больше предыдущего) Как это сделать?

Tags: c#

```
int[] massiv = new int[] {4, 2, 9, 6, 5 };
static void Output2<T>(T[] massiv) where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < massiv.Length; i++)
            {
                massiv[i+1].CompareTo(massiv[i]);
                Console.Write(massiv[i].CompareTo(massiv[i + 1]));
            }
```

Comment: `Разрабатываемый метод должен возвращать истину...` & `void` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, например

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] massiv1 = new int[] { 4, 2, 9, 6, 5 };
    int[] massiv2 = new int[] { 4, 5, 9, 16, 25 };
    Console.WriteLine(CheckArrayIsGrowing<int>(massiv1));
    Console.WriteLine(CheckArrayIsGrowing<int>(massiv2));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static bool CheckArrayIsGrowing<T>(T[] massiv) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < massiv.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (massiv[i + 1].CompareTo(massiv[i]) != 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Результат:

```
False
True
```